Map by last characters in GAMS
Consider the following data in GAMS:
set SCENARIO  / 02, 03 /;
set ER2M      / ER2M01, ER2M02, ER2M03 /;

I want to create the following mapping:
set mapER2MSCENARIO(SCENARIO,ER2M) / 02.ER2M02, 03.ER2M03 /;

That is, I want to map by the last two characters in the element ('02' with "ER2M02", etc.). Is there a way to do that automatically instead of writing it manually?
I have tried:
set mapER2MSCENARIO(SCENARIO,ER2M) / #Scenario:#ER2M /;

But that does not work.
